# Syntax for using Tooltip in DiscretePlot

Tags: tooltip, plotting

`Tooltip` works fine in `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]], {x, 0, 20}]]
```

in which the decimal value of the distribution at a point is revealed when a cursor is placed over that data point.

How does one get the same functionality using `DiscretePlot`?  For instance,

```
DiscretePlot[Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]], {x, 0, 20}]
```

reveals "`PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]`" (rather than the desired numerical value) when a cursor is placed over a data point.

I've tried a number of obvious alternatives, such as `Tooltip` with two arguments and `Evaluate` or `N` (numerical value) applied to the PDF.  None work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a quick fix:

```
DiscretePlot[
  Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]]
  , {x, 0, 20}] /. Tooltip[a_, b_] :> Map[Tooltip[Point[#], Last@#] &, a[[3, 1]]]
```

---

If you investigate under the hood,

```
Cases[
  ListPlot[Table[Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]], {x, 0, 1}]]
  , Tooltip[a__] :> {a}
  , Infinity]
(* { {{Opacity[0.], Point[{{1., 0.0000453999}}]}, 0.0000453999}
     , {{Opacity[0.], Point[{{2., 0.000453999}}]}, 0.000453999} } *)
```

so that each point gets its own `Tooltip` labeled with the value, whereas

```
Cases[DiscretePlot[Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], x]], {x, 0, 1}]
  , Tooltip[a__] :> a
  , Infinity]
(* {{{}, Null, Point[{{0., 0.0000453999}, {1., 0.000453999}}], {}}
     , PDF[PoissonDistribution[10],x]} *)
```

In `DiscretePlot`, the second argument of `Tooltip` is `PDF[PoissonDistribution[10],x]`, which means each point will be labeled with that expression. I do not know why it does this.

Comment: Thanks.  Your quick fix suffices.  Solution accepted.  (I wish there were a more elegant solution, however.)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. There might be! ciao very briefly had a comment with something that almost seemed to work, so perhaps something along those lines might work. As far as `Tooltip` and `DiscretePlot` working together nicely, who knows if there's correct syntax for that. I tend for quick fixes and kluges if it's not *too* inelegant.

Comment: @march: Yes, that was *thiiiisss close*, eh? Afraid it was a dead end, your method seems sound (upvoted it and question). Perhaps one of the deep evaluation spelunkers here can enlighten why one can't get at the evaluated value for use in tooltip, or a way to do it...

Answer (score 8):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER BUT RATHER AN EXTENDED COMMENT.

Your `ListPlot` example is shifted from the proper location since the data is assumed to start with 1 rather than 0. To correct this, you can either enter data points or specify the `DataRange`. You can use the option `Filling->Axis` to get the same format as you would with `DiscretePlot`.

```
ListPlot[
 Tooltip[PDF[PoissonDistribution[10], #]] & /@ Range[0, 20], 
 DataRange -> {0, 20}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes.  You are correct about the unit offset.

Comment: Excellent! Going [meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/protocol-is-it-ok-to-write-a-long-comment-as-an-answer).